# I need a help with this HQ test puzzle I found online

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

<sup>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sup>

---

[image]

**Which option (a.,b.,c.,d. or e.) completes the sequence above?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I propose

> b) or e); more likely e).

Because

> This is a transcription of Frère Jacques sung in a round in the key of C, omitting the treble clef and tails to crotchets and minims. Though the fact that the Dormez-vous? line is an octave below the Frère Jacques line indicates singers with two different ranges. If this is the point where the half line repeats, then the answer is e); if it is the point where the lines change then the answer is b). I tend towards e) as I might expect a third singer to be introduced with b).

My best explanation for this title is

> That this is a High Quality, two person IQ Puzzle but with the first part dropped by an octave.

Comment: Well done, this is the expected answer! Checkmark incoming as soon as you explain the pun in the title!

Comment: I'm just upvoting. I really have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: @JLee rot13(Serer Wnpdhrf vf (snzbhf?) n fbat naq gur frdhrapr vf vgf furrg zhfvp. Guhf gur nafjre vf gur arkg one bs gur fbat)